# Conditions on wave packet to be a solution of the wave equation

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

I am wondering if any wave packet of the form

$$\psi=\int g(\boldsymbol{k}) e^{i(\boldsymbol{k}\boldsymbol{r}-\omega t)}$$

is always a solution to the classical wave equation? In my understanding, this would raise some condition to the amplitude distribution $g(\boldsymbol{k})$. Inserting this into the classical wave equation, we get:

$\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial t^2}=|\boldsymbol{v}|^2\nabla^2 \psi$

$\frac{\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial t^2}}{\nabla^2\psi}-|\boldsymbol{v}|^2=0$

$\int g(\boldsymbol{k}) \left(\frac{\omega^2}{|\boldsymbol{k}|^2}-|\boldsymbol{v}|^2\right) e^{i(\boldsymbol{k}\boldsymbol{r}-\omega t)}=0$

In my understanding, this means that only such $g(\boldsymbol{k})$ are allowed for which $g(\boldsymbol{k}) \left(\frac{\omega^2}{|\boldsymbol{k}|^2}-|\boldsymbol{v}|^2\right)$ vanishes for any time and space.

Is this right? And what does this mean about possible solutions?

Comment: Your wave packet is a linear combination of solutions of the wave equation (i.e. the exponential in the integral, provided that $w(k)=vk$). The wave equation is linear, hence the wave packet is a solution if you substitute $w$ with $vk$ in the integral.

Comment: Thanks. But does that not mean that every wave packet gives a linear dispersion relation? That would not make sense right?

Comment: I think what you are referring to is the case of a non-dispersive wave, for which $\omega=vk$. So for a non-dispersive wave, every wave packet is always a solution. However, what in the case of a dispersive wave, for which $\omega\neq vk$?

Comment: your wave equation is for a non dispersive medium

Comment: The simple wave equation has always the  linear dispersion relations  = ± for sinusoidal waves propagating in opposite directions. The () in your linear superposition integral correspond to the amplitudes of the partial waves which can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general solution can be presented as
\begin{equation}
\int d^3 \vec k \Big[ g_1(\vec k)e^{i|v||\vec k|t-i\vec k\cdot \vec x}+g_2(\vec k)e^{-i|v||\vec k|t+i\vec k\cdot \vec x}\Big]  \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
with arbitrary $g_1(k)$ and $g_2(k)$.
It follows from your formulas, after you express $\omega$ in terms of $k$. Two terms correspond to two ways of taking the square root. If you additionally require that the solution is real, then you need to impose
\begin{equation}
\Big(g_1(\vec k) \Big)^*=g_2(\vec k).
\end{equation}

In (1) the integral goes over spatial $k$ only. In principle, you can make it over all $k$ in space-time (I mean, including $\omega$). Then, as it is clear form what you wrote, you need to solve
\begin{equation}
g(\vec k,\omega)(\omega^2 - |v|^2 |\vec k|^2)=0.
\end{equation}
Its general solution is
\begin{equation}
g(\vec k,\omega) = f(\vec k,\omega) \delta(\omega^2 - |v|^2 |\vec k|^2), \qquad (2)
\end{equation}
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta. Note that in (2) only values of $f(\vec k, \omega)$ at $\omega^2 - |v|^2 |\vec k|^2=0$ are relevant. Indeed, if we replace
\begin{equation}
f(\vec k,\omega)\to f(\vec k,\omega)+(\omega^2 - |v|^2 |\vec k|^2)\alpha (\vec k,\omega)
\end{equation}
with any $\alpha$, then (2) remains unchanged due to $\delta(x)x=0$. The above replacement allows to change values of $f$ arbitrarily everywhere away from $\omega^2 - |v|^2 |\vec k|^2=0$. Thus, only values of $f$ on $\omega^2 - |v|^2 |\vec k|^2=0$ actually contribute to (2).

The general solution than acquires the form
\begin{equation}
\int d^3\vec k d\omega f(\vec k,\omega) \delta(\omega^2 - |v|^2 |\vec k|^2) e^{-i\omega t + i\vec k\vec x}. \qquad (3)
\end{equation}
If you need a real solution, you need to impose
\begin{equation}
f(-\vec k,-\omega) = \Big( f(\vec k,\omega)\Big)^*.
\end{equation}
The solution in this form can be easily connected to (1) if one eliminates the $\omega$ integral using the delta function.

Comment: It seems right, but why is the dispersion relation always linear? For a general wave packet, the dispersion relation might become non-linear right?

Comment: it depends on the equation of motion you solve. If the equation of motion has the mass term, then you get $\omega^2-|v|^2 k^2-m^2=0$. If the equation of motion has higher-derivative terms, you may actually get anything you want. Say, $(\partial_t^2-\nabla^4)\phi=0$ will result in $\omega^2+ k^4=0$

Comment: I think I do not quite get what you mean. Did your derivation not show that $v = \omega/k$, hence a linear dispersion relation for any wave that can be written as a linear superposition of monochromatic waves?

Comment: Yes. Actually, you get a linear dispersion relation for only one equation of motion, which is $(\partial_t^2-\nabla^2)\phi=0$. Though, it is quite an important one, as it describes all massless particles that we have. However, there are many other equations that you may want to solve. If you have a linear differential equation with the coefficients that do not depend on space-time coordinates, then the easiest way to solve it is by going to the Fourier space. Then, the solution is always a superposition of exponents. The dispersion relation can be anything, depending on the equation.

Comment: I got it. I never knew that the classical wave equation always gives a linear dispersion relation, thanks for clarifying this!